# unix list files with a full stop in name

Tags: unix, ls

I have 4 files: the naming convention is as follows:

```
hello.account.sub1.001  
hello.account.sub2.001  
hello.account.sub3.001  
hello.account.sub4.001
```

If I use `ls -l hello.account*001` to search files, no problem exists.

However, problem exists when using `ls -l hello.account.*.001`

The system complains that `No such file or directory`

I assume the system considers hello.account.*.001 is a single file.

This interests me so I ask: how can you search the file if a full stop is specified as searching criteria?

Many Thanks

Comment: `The system complains that No such file or directory` - No, that works for me. Which Shell are you using?

Comment: should still work - file name globbing is done by the shell, unless the pattern is escaped, so you should still see all four files. It would be different if you did `ls -l "hello.account.*.001"`

Comment: Becuase I face this problem in school's unix system, I can't test it currently. I guess I may add quote in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filename globbing](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/globbing) is done by the **shell**, before actually executing the command (such as `ls` in your case). The following works:

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21

$ ls -l hello.account.*.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 andreas users 0 Jul 22 03:59 hello.account.sub1.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 andreas users 0 Jul 22 03:59 hello.account.sub2.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 andreas users 0 Jul 22 03:59 hello.account.sub3.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 andreas users 0 Jul 22 03:59 hello.account.sub4.001
```

while the following does not:

```
$ ls -l "hello.account.*.001"
ls: hello.account.*.001: No such file or directory
```

The reason is that in the first case, the shell expands the file name pattern before executing `ls` - `ls` will then see four different file names passed as arguments.

In the second case, since the file name pattern is escaped with double quotes, `ls` gets the pattern itself passed (which `ls` does not further expand - it looks for a file with the name `hello.account.*.001`)